# jQuery $.when execute order

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Is there a way to execute multiple calls in a specific order using jquery.when?
first customers, second shifts, third params, etc.

```
$.when(
    service.doCall('GET', 'customers'),
    service.doCall('GET', 'shifts'),
    service.doCall('GET', 'params'),
    service.doCall('GET','columns')
).then(function(customers, shifts, params, columns) {}
```

Every call returns a deferred promise which is resolved with the result of the call.
The reason I want to execute them in a specific order is because i'm showing a modal to show which call is being executed and which call is done executing. In my service class I notify using a custom event when that call is done. For example when the customers are loaded:

```
loadingPopup.loadingCustomers.notify();
```

Then in my popup class I listen for these events, as shown below. But since the calls are executed in a random order my events are fired in the wrong order.

```
me.loadingCustomers.attach(function() {
    me.loadCustomersBusy(false);
    me.loadCustomersDone(true);
    me.loadShiftsBusy(true);
});

me.loadingShifts.attach(function() {
    me.loadShiftsBusy(false);
    me.loadShiftsDone(true);
    me.loadParamsBusy(true);
});

me.loadParams.attach(function() {
    me.loadParamsBusy(false);
    me.loadParamsDone(true);
    me.loadColumnsBusy(true);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by specific order

Comment: like after completion of customers, shift, then params, then again when params is over sent the columns request

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dfp9b/2/

Comment: If, as you say, you want an indication of asynch status (executing/completed), then you just need to attach `.done()` and `.fail()` handlers to each of the individual promises to provide the necessary indication. Order would only matter if each `service.doCall()` depended in the previous doCall(s) having completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is *not* to use `$.when` to start the chain of calls:

```
service.doCall('GET', 'customers').then(function() {
    return service.doCall('GET', 'shifts')
}).then(function() {
    return service.doCall('GET', 'params')
}).then(function() {
    return service.doCall('GET','columns')
}).then(...)
```

Note that this won't give you the benefit of `$.when` then automatically being called with all four results, so whilst you shouldn't use `$.when` to *start* the calls, you can use it to create an additional promise that when resolved will be passed the results of *all* previous calls.

```
var def = [];
def[0] = service.doCall('GET', 'customers');
def[1] = def[0].then(function() { return service.doCall('GET', 'shifts') } );
def[2] = def[1].then(function() { return service.doCall('GET', 'params') } );
def[3] = def[2].then(function() { return service.doCall('GET', 'columns') } );

$.when.apply($, def).then(function(customers, shifts, params, columns) {
    ...
});
```

In this case I create an array of deferred objects, but each successive AJAX call isn't started until the previous one has finished.  It then uses `$.when.apply($, def)` to pass all four deferred object results to the final callback.

Comment: missing `return` in front of `service.doCall` to make sure the callbacks return promises. Otherwise the correct solution.

Comment: @Hans ah, yes, I haven't chained the calls properly...  will fix, thanks.

Comment: @Stvenoo if you had more than just four calls I would suggest using a loop to iterate over the parameter values, but for this volume it looked like overkill when I started writing it.

Comment: @Alnitak I currently have 9 calls already so I think a loop is prefered.

Comment: @Stvenoo Do the calls all take the form `service.doCall('GET', foo)` ?

Comment: @Alnitak yes 9 GET's and 1 POST

Comment: @Stvenoo the POST being the final thing done after the 9 GETs all complete, depending on data received from those GETs?

Comment: @Alnitak no, POST only occurs when the user executes a certain action